# realm class property cannot be marked dynamic

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I just upgraded to Xcode 7 and Swift 2 and this line is throwing an `Property cannot be marked dynamic because its type canot be represented in Objective-C`:

```
dynamic var log = List<LogEntry>()
```

Answer (score 8):

Realm changed it's documentation: [Realm Swift 0.95.0](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/)
now you should use `let` instead of `dynamic var`

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#property-attributes (0.97.0)  "There are two exceptions to this: List and RealmOptional properties cannot be declared as dynamic because generic properties cannot be represented in the Objective-C runtime, which is used for dynamic dispatch of dynamic properties, and should always be declared with let."

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and spent a long time trying to figure it out. My main problem was I went through and removed all `dynamic` flags after I saw the compile issue, but it would hardly be able to access any data. It appears to be safe to remove the `dynamic` from all to-many objects, e.g. `List<Object>()` but leave them there on everything else.